# JSON and PHP encode multiply array

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing, encode

In my PHP script, I am trying to encode my multiply news array into JSON.

My news array:

```
$news[1]["header"] = "First header";
$news[1]["content"] = "First news content";

$news[2]["header"] = "Second header";
$news[2]["content"] = "Second news content";
```

I use this function to encode this array:

```
json_encode($news);
```

After that, I send this JSON data in my JS script.

```
var result = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText); // Here is my JSON object
```

How can I get, for example first news header in my JavaScript code?

Thanks for any help. It is really hard for me to unserstand json syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse` creates an object where properties (keys) are `1`, `2`, etc. So you can access the first header with `result[1].header` or `result[1]['header']`.

You can also access the headers by iterating over the result:

```
for (var index in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        console.log(result[index].header);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
First header
Second header
```

**EDIT:** Here is a demo:

```js
var json = '{"1":{"header":"First header","content":"First news content"},"2":{"header":"Second header","content":"Second news content"}}';

var result = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(result[1].header);

for (var index in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        console.log(result[index].header);
    }
}
```

Comment: result[1].header returns nothing

Comment: What's the value of `result` and `xmlHttp.responseText`? Added a demo script to my answer.

Comment: Very strange. Your demo work correct. By my .responseText returns nothing.

Comment: Yes. I just didnt write json_encode in my php script. Now it is working correct. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = '{"1":{"header":"First header","content":"First news content"},"2":{"header":"Second header","content":"Second news content"}}';

var result = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(result[1].header);

for (var index in result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        console.log(result[index].header);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.